# how can I add 3D Transform animation for a sphere with out calling touching events in my ios application

Tags: objective-c, ipad, core-animation

How can I apply continuously 3D transform animation to a view without making any touches in my iPad application. In my application I have a Sphere shaped view and I want to rotate that view in x axis continuously with out any user interaction. Please help me.

Thank you
Lakshmi

Comment: How do you have a "Sphere shaped view"? Views are all 2D

Comment: You could easily rotate that view but that would probably cause your tags to not always face straight forward. Try what happens what you apply a CATransform3D on the view layer and if that looks ok I you could use that to animate the rotation, otherwise you would have to look at the library that created the tag cloud to see if it can do a rotation.

Comment: I tried CATransform3D. what you said is correct tags are not facing straight always I have to try by making changes in tag cloud library. Thank you

Comment: IF you have to code for the tag cloud you can apply a transform in one direction to the cloud itself and then transform all the individual tags the same angle in the other direction. That should have them face forward.